# Is there a difference between "== False" and "is not" when checking for an empty string?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I have read elsewhere on stackoverflow that the most elegant way to check for an empty string in Python (e.g. let's say it's a string called `response`) is to do:

```
if not response:
    # do some stuff
```

The reason being that strings can evaluate to boolean objects.

So my question is, does the below code say the same thing?

```
if response == False:
    # do some stuff
```

Comment: second won't execute if response is NOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned there is a difference.

The `not response` checks if `bool(response) == False` or failing that if `len(response) == 0` so it is the best choice to check if something is empty, `None`, `0` or `False`. See [the python documentation on what is considered "Falsy"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

The other variant just checks if `response == False` and this is only the case *if and only if* `response is False`. But an empty string `is not False`!

Answer (score 9):

Is there a difference? Yes: one works, and the other doesn't.

`if response == False` is only true if the actual value of `response` is `False`. For an empty string, that is not the case.

`if not response`, on the other hand, verifies if `response` is falsey; that is, it is one of the values that Python accepts as false in a boolean context, which includes None, False, the empty string, the empty list, and so on. It is equivalent to `if bool(response) == False`.